# What is the scope of "event" used in HTML attributes for Drag and Drop?

Tags: javascript

HTML has several attributes for Drag and Drop, like ondrag=, ondrop=, etc
For example,

```
<p id="source" ondrag="drag_handler(event);" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event);" draggable="true">...</p>
```

My question is about the argument "event". Its name is hardcoded. Apparently, it is an object. It has a strange scope. It is defined inside the HTML element that uses it but it is undefined outside the element, i.e.

```
 <script> 
    typeof event; // returns undefined
 </script>
```

In Chrome, inside the event handler, (typeof event) returns object that is the same object inside HTML element so that you can actually get rid of the parameter and reference "event" object directly inside event handler. In Firefox, event is undefined inside the event handler so you have to use it as a parameter. It seems like the implementation of Drag and Drop (at least the inline version) is based on kludges.

Where is this "event" object documented? What kind of variable scope is this? How can it be a defined object inside a selected HTML element and undefined inside script element, i.e. defined outside JavaScript but undefined inside JavaScript? What kind of logic is this?

Comment: dragstart_handler call this then check it

Comment: If you can limit this to a single question, it would be easier to answer. You'll want to do some research first, however, as a quick search for `ondrag' found [this guide for using drag and drop in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)...

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like if you'd attached the event handlers in JavaScript (which you *should* be doing), it would look like this:

```
document.getElementById('source').addEventListener("drag",function(event) {
    drag_handler(event);
},false);
```

Notice how `event` is only defined in this function's scope, and nowhere else. It's basically the same thing.